# How do I change the Xamarin.Forms Frame default selected border for Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When a [Xamarin.Forms Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame) is selected, the default Android color is orange. For example:

```
<Frame
  Margin="0"
  Padding="0"
  BackgroundColor="White"
  CornerRadius="8"
  HeightRequest="145"
  HorizontalOptions="Center"
  VerticalOptions="Center"
  WidthRequest="150" />
```

[image: Default Xamarin.Forms Frame border for Android]

How do I change this default color for my entire app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `android:colorActivatedHighlight` value in the `Resources/values/styles.xml` file in your Android project.

[image: Android styles file]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <!-- Sets Frame element border when selected -->
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
  
  ...

</resources>
```